# In kotlin why Array can not be a collection?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, collections

1. this is Class Array object which is not implemented by Iterable and ICollection inteface
   `val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)`

Comment: Arrays are a lower level object type so they don’t implement any interface. This is due to compatibility with the JVM. In Java, Array isn’t a class.

Comment: What would go wrong with implementation to interfaces, if you know what is happening under the hood, what causes this incompatibility with JVM

Comment: It would just not work. You know what is going on internally, but you can't force JVM to work differently than usual. If some method/function accepts `Iterable` then you can't pass an array there, because JVM would throw an exception or even crash entirely. However, I guess Kotlin compiler could at least wrap arrays into objects, similarly to primitives autoboxing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.